# And gate in a demultiplexer

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

I have a question regarding the use of an AND gate in a demultiplexer 1x4 circuit such  as

[image]

A demultiplexer truth table shows you can output a 1 signal on the zero line, if your input is 1, and both your selector line is 0.

My question is why can the  demultiplexer which uses a three input(1 from data and 2 from selector line) AND gate output a 1 signal even though both the input from the selector line is 0?

Isnt the AND gate only output a 1 signal if all the input is equal to 1.

Comment: what is a zero line ?

Comment: Think about what the invertors do?

Comment: @LongPham the line where both of the selector is inverted, this equates to 00 = 00

Comment: @Trevor_G it invert the the selector  to 00, my question is why when both of the line is equal to 0 you can still have an output of 1 if the data input signal is 1, even though the demux uses an AND gate.

Comment: the multiplexer will output the data input to an output(Y0,1,2,3) depending on which state the 2 seclector input are

Comment: See my answer....

Comment: @Trevor_G thx bro you are right, i must not  have look into the circuitry close enough, thx for your awnser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ignoring the invertors. Look more closely at the wiring.

The inputs to Y0 are Data, NOT A, and NOT B

When Data is high and A and B are low, that's three highs on the input = high on the output.

[image]